# VSCODE Terminal Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get the old terminal back in VScode ,as VScode always open new terminsl when we reopen?

Reopening of terminal with all previous commands, so that I will not loose the old session outputs of old session commands. So if it is last ,that involves lot of rework.

Comment: Welcome! 1) As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) 2) get it back after what? after closing VS Code completely and reopening it?

Comment: Can you please check what the value of your `terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions` setting is? The default value is `true`, so I can't understand yet why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `View -> Terminal` instead of `Terminal -> New Terminal`

[image]

[Terminal Basics](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics):

> Use the **Ctrl+`**  keyboard shortcut to toggle the terminal panel.
> Use the **Ctrl+Shift+`** keyboard shortcut to create a new terminal.

Comment: Hi Markus,I asked how to go to old terminal not new terminal

Comment: `View -> Terminal` does not open a new terminal. It shows the hidden terminal

Answer (score 1):

Hide and show the VSCode integrated terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on a Mac).  This runs the `View: Toggle Pannel Visibility` command.